# Isomorphism between $\mathbb{R}$ and $\mathbb{C}$ as additive 'groups'

Tags: group-theory, abelian-groups, group-isomorphism

I know a proof of this using the fact that both $\mathbb{R}$ and $\mathbb{C}$ are $\mathbb{Q}$-vector spaces of the same dimension and hence are isomorphic.

Also, $$\mathbb{C}/\mathbb{R}\cong \mathbb{R}$$ under the surjective map $a+ib \to a$ from $\mathbb{C}\to\mathbb{R}$.

A more general statement could say that two $\mathbb{Z}$-modules are isomorphic if and only if they are isomorphic as abelian groups.
My question is that,

> Is there a group theoretic proof of this?

I'm not able to produce a direct proof because they aren't cyclic and they're vector spaces of infinite dimension. Please help.

Comment: What exactly would a group theoretic proof look like? Saying they are vector spaces of the same dimension seems pretty group theoretic to me.

Comment: Can we construct a bijection between the two and then show that it preserves the group law to show that it is a homomorphism. Hence, an isomorphism.

Comment: This result is reliant on the axiom of choice (indeed it is false without it) and so a direct proof will be hard to come by

Comment: @Sid I highly doubt it can be done explicitly, but you can do it with the axiom of choice by picking a basis in each one and mapping one basis to the other for a linear isomorphism. The linear isomorphism is also a group isomorphism. I think a group can be a vector space over $\mathbb Q$ in only one way, so every group isomorphism will be $\mathbb Q$-linear.

Comment: I see. So, it isn't possible to give such a bijection.